# How to get the error code when there is error in powershell?

Tags: powershell

My snippet is something like this:

```
$msg=Remove-Item -Recurse -Force C:\users\bkp  2>&1
if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 1)
{
  "Encountered error during Deleting the Folder. Error Message is $msg. Please check." >> $LogFile
  exit
 }
```

The folder C:\users\bkp does not exist. Even though $msg gives me the error message $LASTEXITCODE is still 0. How do I capture as a flag?

Comment: You could just check the $error variable. This contains every error encountered in your session, well up to a point as it does have a limit on memory allocation I believe.

Answer (score 43):

You can use the `$?` [automatic variable](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) to determine the result of the last command.  If you need access to the actual error, you can use the `$Error` automatic variable.  The first item in the array is the last error thrown:

```
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force C:\users\bkp 2>&1
if( -not $? )
{
    $msg = $Error[0].Exception.Message
    "Encountered error during Deleting the Folder. Error Message is $msg. Please check." >> $LogFile
    exit
}
```

Comment: I think it would be better to add `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`, so that if cmdlet failed due it wouldn't terminate and skip the if statement. and the error message will not be print to console twice.

Comment: @Jackie Yes, if the OP wants to handle all errors himself. From his original question, though, he is redirecting errors to the standard output stream, so I think he still wants to see them.

Answer (score 15):

$LASTEXITCODE is strictly for command line programs to return their status. Cmdlets that are built into PS, such as Remove-item return their errors in up to 3 ways. For warnings, they write messages (or other .NET objects) to the "warning stream". In PSv3 there is a straightforward way to redirect that stream to a file: `cmdlet blah blah blah 3>warning.out`. The second is via the error stream. That stream can be redirected as well `... 2>error.out`, or more typically errors are caught with try/catch or trap, or written to a variable with the -ErrorVariable parameter (see `help about_commonparameters`). The third way is for errors to be "thrown". Unless caught (try/catch or trap), a thrown error will cause the script to terminate. Thrown errors generally are subclasses of the .NET class `system.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord`. An ErrorRecord provides a lot more information about an error than a return code.

If remove-item fails due to a file not found error, it writes a `System.Management.Automation.ItemNotFoundException` to the error stream. Using a try/catch you can filter for that specific error or other specific errors from remove-item. If you are just typing in PS commands from the command line you can enter `$error[0]|select-object *` to get a lot of info on the last error.

---

You could do this:

```
try {
  Remove-Item -Recurse -Force C:\users\bkp  2>&1
} catch {
  # oops remove-item failed. Write warning then quit 
  # replace the following with what you want to do
  write-warning "Remove-item encounter error: $_"
  return # script failed
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you just want to know if the command worked or not? However it's not always just a yes/no decision. For example you could tell remove-item to delete 10 files, but it ends up deleting 8, because two files are in use by other programs. Do you consider the success or failure? I think you probably want to use try/catch (see help about_try) and if any errors occur then you want the catch the error and go from there. I'll edit the answer to give some sample code

Comment: `try..catch` doesn't work, because the error is non-terminating. You have to add `-ErrorAction Stop` to `Remove-Item` to make the error catchable.

Comment: That's not true. `try {alskjfdlj} catch {'hi'}` shows 'hi'. A command not found exception is not terminating - `asdlkfjls; write-host hi` will display hi. But `throw 'go';write-host hi` will not display 'hi'` (demonstrating that a terminating exception will prevent the write-host from executing)

Comment: @Ansgar After going back and looking at this, I'm seeing some subtle behavior. No matter what $ErrorActionPreference is, a CommandNotFoundException due to an invalid command is catchable. Yet it is only terminating if EA is Stop. On the other hand `remove-item asdlkjlsa` is only catchable (and terminating) if EA is Stop. So we're both right depending on the situation.

Comment: We're talking about an error thrown by an existing cmdlet (`Remove-Item`) due to a non-existing object (`C:\Users\bkp`), not about an error thrown because of a non-existing cmdlet (`alskjfdlj`). Different matters. `try { Remove-Item "C:\nonexisting" 2>$null } catch { "caught" }` won't display `caught` unless `-ErrorAction` or `$ErrorActionPreference` are set to `Stop`. I don't make these things up.

Comment: @Ansgar Actually I was talking about PS behavior around error handling in general. Seemed like OP didn't understand how PS handling differed from CMD.EXE. My reply wasn't specific to remove-item. I don't make 'em up either