# How can I capture the Powershell informational console output to a variable?

Tags: powershell, stream, stdout, redirectstandardoutput

I can't seem to figure out how to capture the quoted text below for parsing. I've tried setting it to a variable as well as redirecting all streams with *>&1 . How can I grab the output text? The *>&1 works for errors, but not for the text below for some reason? Writing to a file is not an option.

```
Connect-Mailbox -Identity $guidT -user $targetDNT -Alias $aliasT -Database $databaseT -DomainController $domainSpecificDCsSourceAccountT[0]
```

I've also tried

```
$outValue = Connect-Mailbox -Identity $guidT -user $targetDNT -Alias $aliasT -Database $databaseT -DomainController $domainSpecificDCsSourceAccountT[0] *>&1
```

> WARNING: The operation completed successfully but the change will not
>   become effective until Active Directory replication occurs.

[edit]
For repro, this command appears to fall into the same situation, and is easier to setup/configure

```
$var = Set-Mailbox $sourceUserT -LitigationHoldEnabled $false
```

[edit2]

Some commands like set-mailbox will work if you change the type from a string to an array such as but connect-mailbox is not able to use that?

So this was kind of dumb luck, it works for the set-mailbox command but not the connect-mailbox command?

```
PS> Set-Mailbox "first.last" -LitigationHoldEnabled $false -WarningVariable wv
    WARNING: The command completed successfully but no settings of 'xxx/last, first' have been modified.

PS> $wv

PS>
```

However when it did it this way

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$wvar = @();
Set-Mailbox "onprem.detailee1" -LitigationHoldEnabled $false -WarningVariable +wvar
WARNING: The command completed successfully but no settings of 'xxxx/last, first' have been modified.

PS> write-host $wvar
The command completed successfully but no settings of 'xxxx/last, first' have been modified.
```

So Powershell cannot cast some outputs (warning, error, etc) to a string, however they can add the object to an array. Strangely enough the non-typing portion of the Powershell language is not applicable here.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `-WarningVariable` [Common Parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters?view=powershell-7) to capture messages destined for the warning stream.

```
Connect-Mailbox -Identity $guidT -user $targetDNT -Alias $aliasT -Database $databaseT -DomainController $domainSpecificDCsSourceAccountT[0] -WarningVariable WarningVar

$WarningVar
```

The common parameters include variable options for messages sent to the error, information, and warning streams.

Comment: Hi, I agree but that was tried and it does not work for this command? I believe it may be an object typing issue?

    PS C:\Users\xx\Documents> 
    PS C:\Users\xx\Documents> Connect-Mailbox -Identity $guidT -user $targetDNT -Alias $aliasT -Database $databaseT -DomainController $domainSpecificDCsSourceAccountT[0] -WarningVariable WarningVar
    WARNING: The operation completed successfully but the change will not become effective until Active Directory replication occurs.
    PS C:\Users\xx\Documents> $warningvar

    PS C:\Users\xx\Documents>

Comment: Maybe it is doing two writes with the second write being empty string. Then it wipes out the variable if the append `+` is not applied.

Comment: Possibly, that would make sense. I can't get either to work with the connect-mailbox command. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: The command behavior does seem bizarre. I've had some good results with calling the code within a script block: `$var = & {Connect-Mailbox ...} *>&1`

Comment: @AdminOfThings, I think the issue is buggy stream behavior when _implicit remoting_ is involved - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way I found to do this was to set erroraction explicitly to stop (`-ea stop`) for the cmdlet in a try catch statement, then I could get the exception value with `$_.Exception.Message` in the catch statement as it forces the cmdlet to have a terminating error.

This is something I've found to be frustrating coming from c# where a try/catch statement works without having to explicitly define an error as terminating or not. If you do not do that for some cmdlets, the try/catch will not work and it will never catch the terminating error.

Hopefully this helps others, more info

https://www.vexasoft.com/blogs/powershell/7255220-powershell-tutorial-try-catch-finally-and-error-handling-in-powershell

Comment: FYI: You can get c# like behaviour by setting `$ErrorActionPreference = [System.Management.Automation.ActionPreference]::Stop` early in your script.  Alternatively you can use `if(-not $?){Write-Warning "An error occurred: '$($Error[0].Exception.Message)'"}`.  Hope that's of some help. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834487/what-is-the-dollar-question-mark-variable-in-shell-scripting and  https://stackoverflow.com/a/17461657/361842

Answer (score 0):

The problem most likely stems from **buggy behavior with respect to streams from *implicitly remoting* commands**, such as created via [`Import-PSSession`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-pssession); [GitHub issue #9585](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/9585) is presumably related.

You have already found one workaround, as demonstrated in your question: if you explicitly create the target variable to pass to `-WarningVariable` as a [`System.Collections.ArrayList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.ArrayList) instance *and* pass the variable name *prefixed with `+`* (`-WarningVariable +var`) - normally intended for *appending* to a preexisting variable value - capturing the warning(s) is possible.

A slightly simpler **workaround** is to **call the command via [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command) and apply `-WarningVariable` to the latter**:

```bash
Invoke-Command -WarningVariable warnings {
  Connect-Mailbox -Identity $guidT -user $targetDNT -Alias $aliasT -Database $databaseT -DomainController $domainSpecificDCsSourceAccountT[0]
}

# $warnings now contains any warnings emitted by the command.
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try the following?

```
$var = myCommand | out-string
```

Comment: Yes, $var is empty that way

Comment: This would only capture _success_ output, and would convert it to a single, multi-line string.